# How does Lorentz invariance link in with CPT symmetry?

Tags: special-relativity, cpt-symmetry

I'm reading several articles on the relation between Lorentz symmetry (invariance under Lorentz transformations) and CPT symmetry; however, they all invoke high-level mathematics which I cannot understand. I would appreciate any intuition or explanation for the link between CPT and Lorentz symmetry which does not rely on heavy mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the three symmetries in  *euclidean* signature (+,+,+,+). Parity  P$:{\bf r}\mapsto -{\bf r}$  is the product of 3 reflections $P_xP_yP_z$. One might think that   T *should* be a reflection in a mirror perpendicular to the  the $t$ direction --- but this changes the $t$ direction of a particle  and so changes the  particle into its antiparticle. Because this is not what we imagine T as doing,  the actual physical (Wigner) $T$ symmetry is a refection $P_t$  in the $t\perp$ mirror together with a charge conjugation, so T= $P_t$C. In the combined operation CPT the two C's undo each other, and as two refections in mirrors intersecting at 90 degrees  is just a rotation through 180 about the axis of intersection, the four reflections combine to give 180 degree rotations in each of the $xy$ and $zt$ planes.

So if the *euclidean* theory is rotationally invariant, it is CPT invariant.    Now --- as an exercise for the reader--- you have to figure out why the same argument goes through in Minkowski $(-,+,+,+)$signature with rotations changed to Lorentz transformations